# matplotlib bar chart with highlights values only

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

Hi I`d like to get a bar chart of this kind. the problem is how to set corresponding xlables by selection?

[image]

I coded as follow to delete undesired country labels but the graph has nan as labels as well.

```
countries=['United States','Mexico','Japan','China','Korea,Rep.','Ireland','France','Italy']
new_index=list(df.index)
for i in range(len(new_index)):
    if new_index[i] not in countries :
        new_index[i]=np.nan
```

And here is my result,with nan in the labels and the distance between bars much wider:
[image]

For the data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Overall Country list
Countries=['United States','Mexico','Japan','China','Korea,Rep.','Ireland','France','Italy','Czech Republic',
 'Austria',
 'Slovak Republic',
 'Slovenia',
 'Germany',
 'Portugal',
 'Hungary',
 'Colombia',
 'New Zealand',
 'Norway',
 'Latvia']

#Countries to highlight
Desired=['United States','Mexico','Japan','China','Korea,Rep.','Ireland','France','Italy']

np.random.seed(0)
Value=np.random.rand(len(Countries))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': Countries,'Value': Value,})
df.sort_values(['Value'],inplace=True)

df.set_index('Countries',drop=True,inplace=True)
ax_1 = df['Value'].plot(kind='bar', title ="graph", figsize=(10, 6), fontsize=12)
ax_1.set_xlabel("Country Name", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you also share the sample dataframe that you are using for this plot? How are trying to plot this graph?

Comment: @ParvBanks thanks for replying. It’s a single column data frame with country name as the index.

Comment: And where do you get the values of 'Percentage point increase per 10 years' ?

Comment: @ParvBanks it’s from an academic paper

Comment: okay, and how are you importing those values in y axis to your dataframe? 
For a plot to work, you need to specify the x co-ordinates (names of countries, in this case) and the y co-ordinates (% points per 10 yrs).

Comment: Basically, the question needs to include a reproducible code for us to work on this example.

Comment: @AILearning Many thanks, the data has been added in the question.

Comment: @ParvBanks Many thanks, the data has been added in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run through the x-ticks and then disable few of them based on `countries` list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Overall Country list
Countries=['United States','Mexico','Japan','China','Korea,Rep.','Ireland','France','Italy','Czech Republic',
 'Austria',
 'Slovak Republic',
 'Slovenia',
 'Germany',
 'Portugal',
 'Hungary',
 'Colombia',
 'New Zealand',
 'Norway',
 'Latvia']

#Countries to highlight
Desired=['United States','Mexico','Japan','China','Korea,Rep.','Ireland','France','Italy']

np.random.seed(0)
Value=np.random.rand(len(Countries))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': Countries,'Value': Value,})
df.sort_values(['Value'],inplace=True)

df.set_index('Countries',drop=True,inplace=True)
ax_1 = df['Value'].plot(kind='bar', title ="graph", figsize=(10, 6), fontsize=12)
ax_1.set_xlabel("Country Name", fontsize=12)



for ticks in ax_1.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    if ticks.label1.get_text() not in Desired:
        ticks.label1.set_visible(False)
        ax_1.patches[df.index.get_indexer([ticks.label1.get_text()])[0]].set_facecolor('w')
        ax_1.patches[df.index.get_indexer([ticks.label1.get_text()])[0]].set_edgecolor('black')
    else:
        ax_1.patches[df.index.get_indexer([ticks.label1.get_text()])[0]].set_facecolor('r')
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks ! But how to select those bars and color them in one color? That`s to say, the selected bar are all colored in red, and the other are kept in white.

Comment: your `if` statement should check `not in desired` instead of `countries`.